# convert param to JSON data inside URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a URL like that and I want to use JSON data coming inside URL

```
"CUNMXSAKU" : {
            "roomCodes" : "DEAL, JRST, JPOV, JSSW, PJRS, PJOV, PJSW, RMOV, RMOF, PRES"
        },
```

My URL

```
 ...._results.html?language=en&hotelInfo={CUNMXSAKU:{roomCodes:DEAL,JRST,JPOV,JSSW,PJRS,PJOV,PJSW,RMOV,RMOF,PRES}}
```

Is it possible to use it ?? I am able to get 
var hotelCode = getQueryParameter('hotelInfo');
as a String

```
{"CUNMXSAKU":{"roomCodes":"DEAL, JRST, JPOV, JSSW, PJRS, PJOV, PJSW, RMOV, RMOF, PRES"}}
```

But when I am trying 
hotelCode.roomCodes , its Undefined.

Please help on this. Is it possible to do with javaScript

Answer (score 1):

When you pull them out of the URL, the params are a string, they're not a javascript object.

Use something like this (in addition to what you have there)

```
var params = getQueryParameter('hotelinfo');
var hotelCode = JSON.parse(params);
```

Then hotelCode will actually contain a proper, walkable javascript object.